# Get body element of site using only javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to retrieve the following sites body content http://sports.espn.go.com/nhl/bottomline/scores?nhl_s_left1 and store it in a string, i know and am successful at retrieving this using php, however i want to restrict to using only javascript, is there a way just to take the string in the site and copy it and store it in a var?

Comment: It's problematic to get content from remote page, but you can check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076648/3208639.

Comment: Hey, Zak, I know it's been 8 years, buuuuut, maybe think about changing the accepted answer?  I hate downvoting old answers because they're essentially wrong. =\

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Although the @Brendan's answer is accepted and correct.

It is simple, short and faster  enough to get a body element using

```
document.body;
```

It does the same as we can do with `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];`, and it should be in the list of answers.

Comment: And to use it even cleaner, just make it a variable `var body = document.body;`

Comment: ... or `document.body.outerHTML` to get as a string

Answer (score 70):

Try this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function get_body() {

  body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
}

</script>
```

Allow me to explain. The `window.onload` is so that the HTML loads before the script is executed. Even though there is only one body tag this is the method i use^. Basically, it finds the "first" body tag there is, then I tell it to just get the body element itself and not all the other attributes and child nodes that go along with it using an index of `[0]`. If you want everything to do with the body tag then lose the index of 0. Hope this Helps!

Comment: Or just `document.body`.

Comment: Yes but if he just wants the tag itself I have presented that option @FelixKling

Comment: Uh? `document.body` returns the same value as `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` and is shorter to write.

Comment: @FelixKing I understand what your trying to say! Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

Yet another option:

```js
let body = document.querySelector("body");
```